# Don't adjust gradient when height changes

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have a `div` with a gradient background and I want that background to stay the same when the height changes, for example when a dropdown is toggled. I made a [barebones CodePen](https://codepen.io/codedbyjordan/pen/qBoxgEV) showing the 'issue'. I've tried `background-attachment: fixed` but that messes with the gradient.

Comment: i suggest giving container `position: relative;` and dropdown `position: absolute; top: 20px;` since that's how dropdowns work anyway

Comment: background-size & background-repeat are here for that kind of purpose : ex:`background-size:100% 250px; background-repeat:no-repeat;` .

Comment: @G-Cyrillus what if I don't know the height?

Comment: @JordanBaron , the height chosen is equal to the min-height set inside the set of rules for that container. But it could be any height you want the gradient to be(second value for background-size) . Height of the container itself should not matter (at least a min-height to show the entire gradient might be a good choice)